# How to get the list of analyzers in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

How to get the list of all analyzers including custom and system ones present in the arangodb.

Thanks,
Nilotpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to arangosh:

```
 a = require("@arangodb/analyzers")
```

output:

```
{
"ArangoAnalyzer" : function ArangoAnalyzer (data) { ... },
"analyzer" : [Function "(name)" ...],
"remove" : [Function "(name, force)" ...],
"save" : [Function "(name, type, properties, features)" ...],
"toArray" : [Function "()" ...]
}
```

Then print the result in a:

```
a.toArray()
```

output:

```
[
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_fi" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_en" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "identity" (type identity)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_de" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_it" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_es" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_ru" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_fr" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_nl" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_no" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_pt" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_sv" (type text)],
[ArangoAnalyzer "text_zh" (type text)]
]
```